# Is there the edit.com application in win7

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, edit

I tried to execute the command `edit file.bat` in command line, but it says that it can't find the command.

When I searched about this, I found that it's an 16bit command and not functional as 64bit.

Are there any similar applications?

Comment: You can run EDIT.COM in 64-bit Windows using DOSBox. https://superuser.com/questions/553227/edit-command-in-windows-8/1495928#1495928

Answer (score 1):

Edit.com has been removed.

Try `NOTEPAD.EXE` or perhaps a decent editor like [EditPlus](http://www.editplus.com)

Comment: im looking for an editor for graphic elements that ar in any other editor like `Í, º, Ä` !